# SQL: Show "running" events

Tags: mysql, sql

my script shows the events of the next 14 days:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
events
WHERE
eventdate
BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

This works fine so far BUT at midnight all "running" (night)events are not displayed anymore.

So the query should output the events from the day before till 5 a.m.

This is my idea but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
events
WHERE
eventdate
BETWEEN DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR)
AND
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Is it because 'eventdate' is a DATE-field?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to subtract 5 hours before doing the comparison:

```
WHERE date_sub(eventdate, interval 5 hour) BETWEEN CURDATE() AND DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```

Alternatively, you can add 5 hours on the other side:

```
where eventdate between now() and datea_add(now(), interval 14*24 + 5 hour)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job or not!?

```
WHERE
eventdate
BETWEEN DATE(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 5 HOUR))
AND
DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL 14 DAY)
```